# Defining function with variables in an array in initialization of class

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, initialization

I have written the following,

```
import numpy as np
class FV:
    def __init__(self,x=0,a=0,b=0,c=0):
        r=np.array([a,b,c])
        self.t=x
        self.s=r
```

but it tells me that:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'r'
```

when I input `P2 = FourVector(ct=99.9, r=[1,2,3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the array instead of creating it inside the function, which you seem to want to do given the line `r=np.array([a,b,c])`.

Assuming `x` is the same as `ct`, try `P2 = FourVector(99.9,1,2,3)`. Otherwise, make sure you decide on whether you want to call your parameter `ct` or `x`. You pass in `ct` but you use `x` inside your function.

You also have a name issue with your class, which you declare as`FV` but you try to use as `FourVector`. Try to be a bit more careful with your names!

Given some decisions about it, your code should look like this:

```
import numpy as np
class FourVector:
    def __init__(self,ct=0,a=0,b=0,c=0):
        r=np.array([a,b,c])
        self.t=ct
        self.s=r
```

which you can then call as

```
P2 = FourVector(99.9,1,2,3)
```

Also note that since you assign `r` and then `s=r`, you can just do `self.s=np.array([a,b,c])` directly, unless you have some reason to keep `r` around separately.